# What's the advantage of using CHAR over VARCHAR?

Tags: sql, sql-server

assuming you data or application doesn't have to match an exact length, why would someone opt to use char (or nchar) over varchar (or nvarchar)?

Comment: It all depends on your data. `VARCHAR` needs an extra byte to account for the variable part (or 2 bytes, don't remember).

Comment: `char(n)` is great for short (max. 5 chars), fixed-length codes like ISO country or currency codes etc. Anything else and longer - use `varchar`. Also, since `char(n)` is a fixed-length column, it's much better suited for an index - especially a primary/clustered index - because it carries no "variable-length" overhead

Comment: @marc_s Why would you suggest storing strings larger than 5 characters in varchar()? Seems like 10 digit zip codes or 38 character GUIDs would be better stored as CHAR(). I mean... 2 extra bytes isn't much, but space is space.

Comment: @JNevill: if you have a longer string that's **always** that given length - OK, store is as `Char(n)`. But I wouldn't store a normal first name as `char(25)` - and waste lots of space on shorter first names in the process.... a GUID should be stored as a GUID - not a string.

Comment: OK That's what I thought. I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything. I was thinking, perhaps, at a certain string length the extra overhead of the two bytes to store the length would be a small enough percentage of the whole that it wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CHAR(100)` always stores 100 bytes (or Characters depending on your RDBMS). `VARCHAR(100)` will store up to 100 bytes plus the necessary number of bytes to store the length of the string.

For instance, if I store "Foo" in `Char(100)` it will take up 100 bytes in my field. If I store "Foo" in `VARCHAR(100)` it will take up 5 bytes. 3 bytes for each character, and 2 bytes for the length of "3".

If you data is variable in length, then use `VARCHAR()` to save space, if it is always the same length use `CHAR()` to save space (because you don't have to write the length with the characters).

Comment: There is also the performance overhead, where some RDBMS will store variable length data off-row, which may be in a different page.

Comment: Can you expand the performance overhead issue?